# Extracting outlook email subject and it's content using Selenium Java

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the particular subject from the various outlook emails and thereafter  I want to extract a particular details from that particular mail.For example:-
Subject name: Details of the customer.
Body Content:
Name- abc 
Address-  USA
Postal code- 456234
In the above example, i want to go to the email with subject "Details of the customer" and extract the deatils like "abc", "USA" and "456234" from Name,Address and Postal code respectively.
Kindly help, to code it using Selenium with Java.

Comment: *I want to [...]* do it, then. StackOverflow isn't a free-code service. You can either do some searches and write some code (and if you have issue with your code, you can post question there), either **pay** a developper to do the job for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, questions like these are [blatantly off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because they address mostly the business logic. In case you have issues with the implementation of your system, try split your problem into [minimal, complete, and verifiable questions about programming issues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).